# Updating a charm on juju charms

Tags: juju, mongodb

I installed mongodb on my juju charms. How do I update it. The version installed from the juju deploy mongodb is version 2.4.I tried to update it using the juju ssh but I kept getting the error "failed to fetch http //repo.mongodb.org". Is there anyway I can instruct mongodb to be updated using the juju statement

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for from the shell prompt on your controller:

```
juju upgrade-charm --force --repository=~/charms mongodb
```

If it throws a config-changed hook failure you could retry the hook:

```
 juju resolved --retry mongodb/0
```

If you don't already have it, you might try adding the juju-gui charm.  You can then see all this in a graphical environment.  I'm pretty sure they allow you to upgrade a selected charm in place in the left panel at the bottom.